# How to get batch_size if shape method in Keras & TF returns None for the batch_size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm wrapping a function as a layer. In this function, I need to know what is the shape of the input. The first index of shape is the batch_size, I need to know it! The problem is that K.int_shape returns something like (None, 2, 10). But, this (None) thing should be known at runtime, right? it is still None and causes an error.

Basically, in my function I want to create a constant that is as long as the batch_size.

Here is my function for what its worth

```
def func(inputs):
    max_iter=3
    x, y= inputs
    c= tf.complex(x, y)
    print(K.int_shape(c))
    z= tf.zeros(shape=K.int_shape(c), dtype='complex64')
    #b=K.switch(K.greater( tf.abs(c) , 4), K.constant(1, shape=(1,1)), K.constant(0, shape=(1,1)))
    for i in range(max_iter):
        c= c * c + z
    return c
layer= Lambda(func)
```

You can see where I created the constant z. I want its shape to be equal to the input shape. But this is causing an error with massive trace. If I replace that with a fixed shape it works. I traced the error to this damn None thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `int_shape`, you can use `tf.zeros_like` to create `z`

```
z= tf.zeros_like(c, dtype='complex64')
```

Comment: Simple and genius.